# В анонимном классе не выполняются действия, в консоль ничего не выводит

Tags: java

```
public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    animal m = new animal();
    m.action(new Dead(){

    @Override
    public void moare() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("doSmth");       
    }});

    }
}

public class animal {

public void action(Dead o){}

}

public interface Dead {
    public void moare();
}
```

Я написал этот пример, чтобы разобратся и понять работу анонимных классов.

Comment: приведите код класса `animal`, описание `Dead`

Comment: Очевидно, что метод moare просто не вызывается. Как правильно пишут, приведите код класса animal.

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть так:

```
public void action(Dead o){}
    o.moare()
}
```

Comment: так получилось , наверное я не понял логику анонимных классов,я создал объект класса animal вызвал на нем метод .action() где передал как параметр анонимный класс который имплементит интерфейс Dead и реализует метод .moare().
 почему я должен также вызвать этот метод  в классе animal  в методе action() ?

Comment: а как по вашему программа будет знать, что надо вызывать moare() а не какой-либо другой метод? сейчас ваш код не делает ничего в action()